# Can call imagecreatefromjpeg() with data-uri as parameter?

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I used data-uri `data:image/jpeg;base64,BASE64_HERE` to pass the image. Can I pass this value `imagecreatefromjpeg()` to save as an image file.

How does this function work?

Comment: Will share the relevant code snippets you might have tried yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imagecreatefromjpeg()` function creates image `variable` from file, but not backwards. While you have image source in `base64` you can use simple `file_put_contents()` function to save file. Eg.:

```
$data = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,BASE64_HERE';

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

file_put_contents('/tmp/image.jpg', $data);
```

You can also use `imagecreatefromjpeg()` and then `imagejpeg()` method if it's more preferable to you. But best method is to use [imagecreatefromstring()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php), because it will automatically detects whenever image is `jpg`,`gif`,`png` or etc. Eg.:

```
$data = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,BASE64_HERE';
$image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($data));
imagejpeg($image, 'image.jpg');
```

Comment: k fine..  but when I used `$data = 'data:image/png;base64,BASE64_HERE';
 imagecreatefrompng($data);` Then its worked properly. Is there any difference between the working of these functions? or can you explain how these functions work ? And thanks for your quick reply

Comment: When you use `$im = imagecreatefrompng()`, you still have to save to file with other function like `imagepng($im,'image.png');` or if you want to display it `header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im); `.

Comment: The difference is that `imagecreatefrompng()` and `imagecreatefromjpeg()` only saves image in *image variable* & not saving it to file.

Comment: thats right.. I just call the function `imagepng($im, $filename)` and `imagejpeg($im, $filname)` to save the files

Comment: I updated my answer with additional `imagecreatefromstring()` method, which i think is most suitable in your case. If given methods answers your question, don't forget to accept it :)

Comment: got it  Thnak you..  I missed the `base64_decode()`